# 'refactor' move files in VSCode - es6

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, refactoring

If I move `ComponentFoo.js` from folder X to folder Y, than a bunch of import statements break.  Looking into this it seems there are many solutions for typescript, but what about js / es6?  If I move a file in the editor, it should find all the import statements and update them to the new location. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14):

Old post, but this might help some Googlers. This feature can be enabled and disabled in User Settings. For Javascript and Typescript, it's called "Update Imports On File Move". The settings are placed under *Extensions → TypeScript*. Their names are

- `javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled`
- `typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled`

so searching for *updateImportsOnFileMove*  will find them both.

[image: Update Imports screenshot]

I had apparently disabled it and just figured the feature was broken :X

Comment: This is now enabled by default for Typescript users. It may be worth noting that this only takes effect when *moving* files, not when *copying*.

Answer (score 5):

for flutter developers you should move files one by one. vscode doesn't support multi file moving with refactor yet.

Comment: *sadness*, good to know, was looking everywhere why only 1 file moving at a time was working

Answer (score 1):

VS Code has built-in support for this for both javascript and typescript [since VS Code 1.24](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_update-import-paths-when-a-file-is-moved-or-renamed).

For JavaScript specifically, you need to make sure VS code's language support can find all the references to the file so that imports referring symbols in that can be updated properly. Definitely create a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) for your project, and also consider [enabling semantic checking for JavaScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking)  so that VS Code shows when imports are not being properly resolved

If your project is configured properly but files are not being updated, make sure you are running the latest VS Code insiders build and report an issue if it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Just use IntelliJ. It handles all kinds of refactoring perfectly. I'm a huge fan of VS Code, but refactoring is definitely not one of its strengths. Some imports don't get detected, and the imports can get modified in a weird way. For example, I had an import like this:

```
import { myStore} from 'src/common/stores/myStore';
```

When moving the file of myStore.ts to a different folder, VS Code constructed this bull**it:

```
import { myStore} from 'src/common/composables/myStoreStore';
```

The line above is no typo!

Btw I'm using vetur, maybe that's causing it, I don't know ...

Comment: Funny enough I'm having the same issue using Intellij